# How do I debug not working characters in PHP/HTML/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, html, utf-8

I am building a webpage in HTML with PHP and MySQL and I ran into trouble with swedish characters ÅÄÖ when running page. They show up as � instead of Å/Ä/Ö.

I have set the charset to UTF-8 in both HTML meta-tag and via PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 
?> 

<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Also, MySQL runs `utf8_general_ci` collation on all tables.

All files should also be encoded and saved as UTF-8 without Unicode Signature (BOM) and no normalization form.

All this have worked flawless before, but today, nomather what I try I do end up with � instead of Å/Ä/Ö. Is there a good way to debug this and find the problem?

Is any of my steps unnecessary or have I forgotten anything?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? Do you have any means to check that the responseheaders really turn out as UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need from [deceze's article](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) is the part regarding the SET NAMES:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection); //not mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Just add that at the beginning of your php code, after the database connection was started

Comment: Where am I using `SET NAMES`? You should not do that, but use `mysql_set_charset` instead.

Comment: Hello. I was reffering to this part: $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=encoding_test;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass',
               array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));

If I didn't understand your article correctly, could you please explain?

Comment: For PDO it's ok to use (though you should specify the charset in the connection string in newer versions that support it). For the old `mysql_` extension, use `mysql_set_charset`. Otherwise you are prone to problems with `mysql_real_escape_string`, since you are changing the encoding on a database level without properly informing the PHP `mysql_` functions about the change.

Answer (score 0):

You may try save your php files in UTF-8 encoding. I assume the files are written in something else (possibly ISO-xxxx or ANSI)

To do that with Notepad++, select all the lines and copy to clipboard, change the coding to UTF-8 without BOM in encoding menu, then paste over everything and save.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for only few records or all records with swedish characters?

You can change the page encoding manually in browser settings - this is how you test it: change it to latin1/iso-8854-1 to see if it displays these correctly that are wrong as utf-8.

Chances are someone is using browser that is not supporting utf8 or fiddled with the encoding manually.

Also make sure you db connection is utf8 too. (`set names utf8;`)